# Ruby/Rails: Converting a range into a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the simplest way to convert the range `1..10` into a hash of the following format?

```
{
  1 => '£1',
  2 => '£2',
  # ...
}
```

I have tried doing this with `map`, but end up with an array of hashes rather than a single hash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Hash[(1..10).map { |num| [num, "£#{num}"] }]
```

or

```
(1..10).inject({}) { |hash, num| hash[num] = "£#{num}"; hash }
```

or in Ruby 1.9

```
(1..10).each_with_object({}) { |num, hash| hash[num] = "£#{num}" }
```

Comment: Methods like `each_with_object` remind me how much I love Ruby! +1

Comment: needs to SWITCH the |hash, num| to |num, hash| in that last example... else get NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for 1:Fixnum

Comment: @jpwynn..yes..you are right. The order is reverse. will update it in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
h = {}
(1..10).each {|x| h[x] = "£#{x}"}
```

Comment: Simple rule of thumb - every time you declare an empty value (hash or array) and then iterate over collection to fill/sum it - use `inject`

Comment: @iafonov..for array, you can use `map`.

Comment: @iafonov I realise this is an old post, but I saw your comment (and I'm new to Ruby), and it just left me wondering *why* you should use `inject`. I'm not saying it's wrong or anything, I'd just like to understand the reasons behind it as the `each` approach above is easy to read and understand - and as I understand it, does the job.

Answer (score 1):

another way

```
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = "£#{key}" }
```

each element will have appropriate value hovever it will also respond to `h[100]` what might cause bugs